# Change Django field with only the string as a key

Tags: python, django, types, typeerror

I want to change the data of a Django field with only the string as a key.

Example:

```
person = Person.objects.get(pk=1)

person['name'] = 'John'

person.save()
```

My Code:

```
changes: dict[str, Any] = json.loads(request.body)


user: User = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

for key in changes.keys():
  user[key] = changes.get(key)

user.save()

response = json.dumps([{ 'Success' : 'User changed successfully!'}])
return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
```

I get the following error message:

> TypeError: 'User' object does not support item assignment

How should I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use setattr:

```
for key in changes.keys():
  setattr(user, key, changes.get(key))

user.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `**<dict_name>`([dictionary unpacking](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/dict_unpack.html)) to update model field values in place:

```
User.objects.filter(id=user_id).update(**changes)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify `updated_fields` when saving object in addition to other answers:

```
updated_fields = []
for key, value in changes.items():
    if hasattr(user, key):
        setattr(user, key, value)
        updated_fields.append(key)

user.save(update_fields=updated_fields)
```